# Postgres Prepared Transactions vs Prepared Statements

Tags: postgresql

I'm fine tuning a Postgres database and I am about to set the maximun number of  with prepared transactions with max_prepared_transactions.

The application uses a lot of prepared statements but not prepared transactions in the sense PREPARE name AS xyz.

My question is:

1. Is there a difference between prepared statements and prepared
   transactions?
2. Does max_prepared_transactions affect prepared statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes. [PREPARE TRANSACTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare-transaction.html) is used to initiate a two-phase transaction, which is generally used if you want to commit atomically to two databases at the same time.

   Prepared statements relate to requesting the server to plan an SQL statement ahead of time, usually so that you can execute the statement multiple times without the overhead of planning it each time. See [PREPARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html).

   The two are unrelated.
2. No, [`max_prepared_transactions`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PREPARED-TRANSACTIONS) does not affect prepared statements.

Comment: Agreed, and I **strongly** advise leaving `max_prepared_transactions` at zero unless you use prepared transactions. A "forgotten" prepared xact can cause a real mess in the DB.